# Find when the next cronjob is due?

Tags: bash, cron

Is there way to show time till next cronjob on command line. I want to find when is next cronjob due from Bash prompt.

Answer (score 1):

`crontab -l` will output something like this:

`50 23 * * * /root/dbbackup`  // ( in my case )

which meant at 11:50 PM everyday the command will execute. So you can easily calculate the time from now.